# Sending Two Strings to JOption List Menu

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, jdbc, joptionpane

So I have this:

```
while(results.next())               
            {               
                // Put into interactive list    
                a.add(hospital);
                hospital = results.getString("hospitalName");
                {   
                    // Loops each hospital via popup, needs to be added to a selection menu
                    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, hospital, "Hospital List", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    System.out.println(hospital);               
                } 
            }

                {
                // Displays list of hospitals
                  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please choose a hospital", "Determined Hospitals",
                          JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, new Object[] 
                          {hospital}, a);
                }
```

It prints both hospitals of the array to the console so I know it finds them. However when I try and display them to the user in a listbox through JOption, it only displays the latest (second) hospital and not the first.

Am I skipping the first string?

Comment: The JOptionPane part is not in a loop, the other part is. That is why it prints both but only shows an option for the last one.

Comment: Does `int i; i = 3; i = 5; System.out.println(i);` print 3 5, or just 5?

Comment: Well I put it in the loop, it generates a list option for each but not both together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this with:

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
            String hospital = null;

            while (results.next()) 
            {
                // Put into interactive list    
                hospital = results.getString("hospitalName"); 
                {
                    // Loops each hospital via popup, needs to be added to a selection menu
                    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, hospital, "Hospital List", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    System.out.println(hospital);
                a.add(hospital);
                }
            }

            {
                // Add the hospital to the array of hospitals found
                Object[] options = a.toArray();

                // Give operator the choice of hospital suited for the patient             
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please choose a hospital", "Determined Hospitals", 
                         JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,  null, options, options[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are skipping the first `hospital` is because of this line here:

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please choose a hospital", "Determined Hospitals",
                      JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, new Object[] 
                      {hospital}, a);
```

Here you are adding in a new `Object[]` that only has the option `hospital` which gets set to the second one. What you are looking for is to do:

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please choose a hospital", "Determined Hospitals",
                      JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, a, a[0]);
```

This will set the options to all of `a` and set the initial value to the first `hospital` in `a`.

Comment: Alright, well upon implementing this I received an error but I think it's because of the way I've made the ArrayList? 
 ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: That's because you need to be using a `String[]` not an `ArrayList<String>`. Replace `a` with `a.toArray();` and you should have no problem running it.